# Mudando a orientação da tela

Tags: javascript, pwa

Meu website PWA tem a seguinte diretriz no `manifest.json`:

```
"display": "standalone",
"orientation": "portrait"
```

Garantindo assim que seja visualizado em tela cheia e sempre em orientação retrato.

Uma certa parte, em específico, precisa ter a orientação mudada para paisagem.
Porém como o `manifest` definiu a orientação de início, não sei como altera-la.

Tentei incluir um novo `manifest` com `"orientation": "landscape"` porém sem sucesso.

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: É gambiarra, mas as vezes dependendo do que for vc consegue resolver se rotacionar o container 90° :), já vi em alguns casos essa técnica sendo aplicada, mas foi junto de @media etc... mas lembro que pra situação resolveu

Comment: Dentro do manifest tem uma propriedade scope, se não me engano serve para aplicar aquele manifest a uma parte (URL) específica. Pode ter faltado isso no seu

Answer (score -2):

Para setar a orientação de tela do PWA você precisa que sua aplicação esteja no modo de tela cheia. Pelo menos é a solução que eu encontrei.

https://hearthero.medium.com/locking-orientation-for-ionic-pwas-7c75c5bb3639

> Technically a locked screen is just a fullscreen view with a forced orientation.